# What's the point of concurrent lists and sets when there is AtomicReferenceArray?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, atomic

To my understanding, the [AtomicReferenceArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html) class allows the individual elements to be updated atomically. This would make the collection thread-safe. Concurrent collections employ various algorithms to allow the collection to be thread-safe, but also non-blocking. I understand that some of the collection classes provide convenient methods, like `add(...)`, or certain functionality like queuing. But ignoring that, and focusing solely on adding and retrieving elements, is there a reason to use one of the concurrent collections rather than an AtomicReferenceArray?

Also, what about performance?

Comment: Probably the same reason why you would use an ArrayList instead of an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there a reason to use one of the concurrent collections rather than an AtomicReferenceArray?

Yes, if you need a dynamically sized collection.  The `AtomicReferenceArray` allows you to atomically get and set elements in the array but you cannot grow the size of the array.

Two threads *can* reliably change the same element in an `AtomicReferenceArray` with `compareAndSet(...)` and other methods, but they can't just add data to the array like you can a collection.  Using an `AtomicReferenceArray` is useful if, for example, each thread has a unique ID and they are updating their personal value in the array.  But this would not work if you have two producers who want to add a job to a work list.

Lastly, the complexity of the `AtomicReferenceArray` is much less than a true concurrent collection.  Concurrent collections allow iterators, deletes, adds, etc. to happen concurrently, safely.  The `AtomicReferenceArray` class allows test and set spin loops and other functionality but is not a good replacement for a full blown collection.

Comment: +1 It has a compareAndSet allowing multiple threads to update the same cells. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html#compareAndSet%28int,%20E,%20E%29

Comment: Yeah, that's not entirely clear in my answer.  I'll tweak.  Thanks @PeterLawrey.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent non-blocking collection algorithms will outperform blocking algorithms by orders of magnitude on multi-core machines. That is the most important reason to prefer concurrent algorithms.

Check out the [LMAX](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html) architecture for more on the drastic performance gain of non-blocking algorithms.

Comment: Aren't atomic operations concurrent by default?

Comment: No. By definition they are not "concurrent." They are single-threaded through the operation. So an atomic operation ensures only one thread performs the whole operation. Whereas a concurrent algorithm as applied to lists for example will allow multiple threads to perform read/write operations without requiring synchronization. It is the synchronization requirement that is extremely expensive (implemented as spin-locks in multi-core CPUs).

Answer (score -1):

Concurrent collections and AtomicReferenceArrays have very little in common. Not sure how you want to compare them. They have different purposes and properties.

Comment: How so? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: The question is not really specific about the kind of _thread-safety_. So, to really answer the question (which is a comparision of two things), one must know what these two things are, namely, what _concurrent collection_ we are talking about. There is e.g. a ConcurrentHashMap, which provides no atomic insert operation; same goes for ConcurrentLinkedQueue/Deque. CopyOnWrite-Collections provide atomic inserts, but at the expense of throwing away the original collection. They have huge performance drawbacks for write access, not to mention garbage overhead for frequent updates.

Comment: For _solely adding and retrieving elements_, that is, if you know the index at which to add an object, and if all obects fit in the array, you will be a lot faster and thread-safe. But this really is not what the Collection classes are intended for, making the comparison a bit moot.